# Updating Time-To-Event distribution given quantity of time elapsed with no event occurence

Tags: bayesian, survival

I'm trying to find a method to update a time to event distribution given the passage of time without the event occurring.

For example, if I am waiting for a bus and the time to arrival can be modeled by an exponential distribution with rate 1/8, then how would I update the distribution after waiting 2 minutes without a bus arrival? I know that the first two minutes now have a probability density of 0, but how is the rest of the distribution modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot conclude the first two minutes now have "a probability density of 0" just because you did not observe an arrival in that time. If the time between arrivals is truly exponential, then there is a postive probability of an arrival in the next two minutes regardless of your single observation. Also, the distribution is memoryless, so think about what that means.

One way to estimate your arrival rate is simply to add up all of the observed arrivals and divide by the total observation time.

Comment: The prior distribution will have positive probability in the first two minutes, but I'm not looking for a prior. Maybe stated this way: How can I determine the probability that a bus will arrive at 12:05 if the bus leaves at 12:00, and has an exponential arrival distribution with rate parameter 1/8 (mins), given that 2 minutes have elapsed (it is now 12:02) without an arrival. If two minutes have elapsed, no posterior distribution should show positive probabilities between 12:00 and 12:02...but my question is, how is the rest of the distribution calculated?

Comment: This question has been considered before. Here is a link: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51292/bayesian-parameter-estimation-of-a-poisson-process-with-change-no-change-observa Also, here is a preview of a paper by Buck, Pignatiello, and Raz that deals with your question: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07408179508936756#preview